# How to prevent adding the empty CDATA elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

The below is used XSLT and input/output XML. The output XML contains the empty CDATA elements. How to prevent adding it without excluding from cdata-section-elements?
XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="first second" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="first second"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <first>
        <second/>
    </first>
    <first>
        <second><![CDATA[! Please note...]]></second>
    </first>
</top>
```

Output with strip-space

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <first>
      <second/>
   </first>
    <first>
      <second><![CDATA[! Please note...]]></second>
   </first>
</top>
```

Output without strip-space

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <first><![CDATA[
        ]]><second/><![CDATA[
    ]]></first>
    <first><![CDATA[
        ]]><second><![CDATA[! Please note...]]></second><![CDATA[
    ]]></first>
</top>
```

Comment: Which is the output you expect given that you have the `first` element designated as a CDATA section element and it has a child element?

Comment: The above sample reflects real documents structure and content. The `first` and the `second` elements may have a CDATA section. The above identity template works as expected if `first` or `second` contains CDATA. Also input XML may have nested `second` in the `first` without CDATA. I expected the same output as an input while applying identity template.

Comment: I asked about the expected output. If you think that an identity transformation in XSLT is supposed to preserve CDATA sections, then no, it does not, the XML is parsed by an XML parser into a tree model underlying XSLT/XPath which does simply have text nodes, that input tree is transformed into a result tree where text node children of certain elements can be serialized as CDATA sections if asked for with `xsl:output cdata-section-elements`. But that is a result tree serialization step that then serializes the text nodes as CDATA section, it does not depend on the input markup format.

Comment: Sorry for not the clear question and thank you for clarification. I updated the input file and provided output with/without 'strip-space'. The output with strip-space is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword to the solution is [function strip-space](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip). Go ahead with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="first"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="first second"/>
    ...
```

To be precise there are whitespace-text nodes between these two nodes:

```
<first>
    <second/>
```

The `CDATA` can't ignore these whitespaces, otherwise it would change the content. So you have to command the processor, what to do with these text-nodes.

---

**Second possible solution**: You address the whitespace-text via template and remove them:

```
<xsl:template match="first/text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="second"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Although I don't quite see the point of this exercise, as the output is identical to the input - both semantically and lexically (except possibly the amount of indent).